# BlackBerry 10 - Problems with touchstart, touchend and touchmove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blackberry-webworks

Currently I am trying to get touch events work on an app running on Q10. The app is built using Webworks, HTML 5, JavaScript and jQuery.

```
strPendList += '<div id="pendingContainer" class="pendingContainer">';
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var pendRefNo = data.result[i].refno;
  var pendRequester = data.result[i].requestor;
  var pendDate= data.result[i].date;
  var pendAmount = data.result[i].amt;

  strPendList += '<div class="pendClaimDisplay" onmouseover="refHighlight(this)" onmouseout="noRefHighlight(this)" onclick="getQClaimParticulars(\''+pendRefNo+'\')">';

  strPendList += '<div class="pendRefLabel">REF NO </div>';
  strPendList += '<div class="pendRefValue">: '+pendRefNo+'</div>';
  strPendList += '<div class="pendRequesterLabel">REQUESTER : </div>';
  strPendList += '<div class="pendRequesterValue maxDisplay">'+pendRequester+'</div>';
  strPendList += '<div class="pendDateLabel">DATE </div>';
  strPendList += '<div class="pendDateValue">: '+pendDate+'</div>';
  strPendList += '<div class="pendAmountLabel">AMOUNT : </div>';
  strPendList += '<div class="pendAmountValue">'+pendAmount+'</div>';
  strPendList += '</div>';//end of pendClaimDisplay
}
strPendList += '</div>';//end of pendingContainer
$('#content').html(strPendList);
```

`data.result` is being retrieved from web services and will be used to generate `listing(pendClaimDisplay)`. I tried to add a highlight effect but `onmouseover(refHighlight)` is not working on the device.

I tried to replace `onmouseover` to:

```
strPendList += '<div class="pendClaimDisplay" ontouchstart="refHighlight(this)" ontouchend="noRefHighlight(this); getQClaimParticulars(\''+pendRefNo+'\')">';
```

But now I could not scroll down the listing as `ontouchend` is being fired whenever I try to scroll up or down the listing.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Edit:

```
function refHighlight(that) {
  $(that).css({'background-color':'#990000'});
}

function noRefHighlight(that) {
  $(that).css({'background-color':''});
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `refHighlight` and `noRefHighlight`? Sounds like you're preventing the default event from triggering

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure why your code isn't working for you, but one thing I found useful when dealing with annoying touch issues was to use a library called Hammer.js

Here's a sample app I made that uses it: https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/gestures